# Different PLS model when using plsr() function in R or Minitab PLS regression menu

Tags: r, partial-least-squares, minitab

I have a PLS model made in R with `plsr()` function (from package `pls`); I have chosen the right number of components with cross validation and it runs fine, with high levels of `R^2_predicted` (>0,85 which is reasonably good for my application).
I was trying to check if the model built under R it's the same I can get with Minitab when analyzing the same data set with the `PLS` regression tool

(**Menu Stat -> Regression -> PLS**).

I'm using exactly the same data set in R and in Minitab but no way to obtain the same model: when I compare the coefficients in the R model using

```
coef(PLS_model, ncomp = N_selected, intercept = TRUE)
```

with the output from Minitab (`Coefficents` table) I get different results.

I have tried several algorithms (`kernelpls`, `simpls`, `oscorespls` which all can be used in function `plsr()`) and also different functions (like `pls1_nipals()` from package `chemometrics`) but they all give very similar answers and none of them goes close the Minitab output. 
According to the manuals, Minitab should use the NIPALS algorithm, as `oscorespls` also does.

The models are built with the following syntax for package `pls`:

```
PLS_model_a = plsr(Y~., data=train_data, n_comp_max=20, validation="LOO", method="kernelpls")
```

and this one for package **"chemometrics"**:

```
PLS_model_b = pls1_nipals(X, Y, 20,)
```

The model generated in these two ways are identical but for both of them the coefficients differ significantly from the Minitab output. Please note that also the Minitab model is a good one with high `R^2_pred`.

Anyone tried to do the same comparison? Any suggestion?
Thanks for your help!